# Create a slide show to move images from left to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this code

```
setInterval(function() {
var $a = $('#slide .active');
    var $n =  $a.next().length ? $a.next() : $('#slide img:first');    
    $n.addClass('active');
    $a.removeClass('active');
}, 1000);
```

This shows all images one by one. I want to show images from left to right but I don't know how?

```
What should I change here?
```

Comment: why not use a plugin for this?

Comment: I want to learn how to do it.

Comment: Then you should make a jsfiddle showing what you have so far with your CSS and HTML : )